# Deleting one to zero or one related data in Entity Framework Core while detached (sqlite)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, entity-framework-core

I'm using Entity Framework Core 1.1.0 and I got two entities:

```
class One
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public ZeroOrOne Property { get; set; }
}

class ZeroOrOne
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

And the following context configured as such:

```
class TestContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<One> Ones { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Filename=local.db");
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }
}
```

I confirmed that the relationship between One and ZeroOrOne to be what I think is indeed One to Zero or One:

```
 migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Ones",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("Sqlite:Autoincrement", true),
                PropertyId = table.Column<int>(nullable: true),
                Text = table.Column<string>(nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Ones", x => x.Id);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_Ones_ZeroOrOne_PropertyId",
                    column: x => x.PropertyId,
                    principalTable: "ZeroOrOne",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
            });
```

If I run the following program...

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var one = new One { Property = new ZeroOrOne(), Text = "Adding related"};
        using (var context = new TestContext())
        {
            context.Database.Migrate();

            context.Ones.Add(one);

            context.SaveChanges();


        }
        one.Text = null;
        one.Property = null;

        using (var context = new TestContext())
        {
            context.Ones.Update(one);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

I expected the end result to be the table One to contain null to both the Text and Property columns. This is true for the Text but not for the Property column.

My question is, is this a bug or it is one of the shortcomings of not tracking the entity? How would I go around this problem given that the entity must be changed while not being tracked by any context?

Should I have to query for One again and go about manually nullifying on the second context instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say if it's a bug or shortcoming (with the current EF Core state one never knows if something is working or not, why and if the behavior will change in some future version or not).

Looks like the navigation and shadow properties are not marked as modified by the `Update` call. Hence the current workaround could be to manually do that:

```
context.Ones.Update(one);
context.Entry(one).Reference(e => e.Property).IsModified = true;
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: That did the trick. I guess I'll try and file a bug on their github page.

Answer (score 1):

I've filed the [this bug](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/7385) on the EF core github, which was promptly closed. I then was helped by ajcvickers to find a solution which I judge to be the best workaround, based on my current understanding of things:

Add the explicit foreign key to the `One` POCO class:

`public int? ZeroOrOneId { get; set; }`

I also renamed Property to be less confusing to:

`public ZeroOrOne ZeroOrOne { get; set; }`

When setting the navigation property to `null`, also set the explicit foreign key to null.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var one = new One { Property = new ZeroOrOne(), Text = "Adding related"};
    using (var context = new TestContext())
    {
        context.Database.Migrate();

        context.Ones.Add(one);

        context.SaveChanges();


    }
    one.Text = null;
    one.ZeroOrOne = null;
    one.ZeroOrOneId = null;

    using (var context = new TestContext())
    {
        context.Ones.Update(one);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Now the update works as I expected.